# Is it possible to have a contextually dependent menu in the master layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have a shared file that's called _SubMenu.cshtml, but this needs to be implemented in all of my views, which I find to be cumbersome and possibly unnecessary(?).

Therefore, I'm wondering if there's such a thing as a 'proper' way to implement a contextually dependent menu in the shared master layout file that changes depending on your rendered view in RenderBody()?

Should each individual controller handle this, or is this something that is to be handled elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a controller-specific `_SubMenu.cshtml`, as follows:

```
~/Views/Controller1/_SubMenu.cshtml
~/Views/Controller2/_SubMenu.cshtml
~/Views/Controller2/_SubMenu.cshtml
```

Then in your `Layout`:

```
@Html.Partial("_SubMenu")
```

The View-Engine will then fetch the appropriate `_SubMenu` based on the current controller.

Alternatively, if you insist on using single `_SubMenu` partial, you can `switch` on the current controller and render the appropriate html:

```
<div id="menu">
    @switch (this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower())
    {
        case "controller1":
            <a href="#">Controller 1 Action</a>
            <a href="#">Another Controller 1 Action</a>
            break;

        case "controller2":
            <a href="#">Controller 2 Action</a>
            <a href="#">Another Controller 2 Action</a>
            break;
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Is that not sort of the same as what I'm currently doing? The whole point for me is to have one shared layout file to maintain and be able to display it when I want based on what view is currently rendered.

Comment: Thanks! Do you consider the last approach you added in your edited post to be bad practice, and if so, why? :)

Comment: Seems harder to maintain to me (relies on 'magic-strings' and future controllers will require modifications of the layout).

Answer (score 0):

You could use child actions. The idea is to have a controller action like this:

```
public class SomeController: Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        SomeViewModel model = ...
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

and then you will have a corresponding partial view:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
```

that could be included in your layout or view:

```
@Html.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")
```

Phil Haack blogged about child action here: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could also have the master/shared layout check for a specific ViewData || ViewBag value.

```
@if(ViewData["_ContextMenuList_"] is List<ContextMenuItem>) {
       /// render the rest of the menu directly or in  a strongly typed partial view. 
}
```

I would use a list of objects that have the Menu text, an action, a controller, htmlClass and some route values.

```
public class ContexMenuItem
{
    public string MenuText { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public object RouteValues { get; set; }
    public object HtmlValues { get; set; }
}
```

Then set this value only in the Controller actions where it makes sense and also fill it with relevant contextual data.

```
// Inside some controller action. 
//asuming some how you already got your client's info. 
        var contextMenu = new List<ContexMenuItem>();
        contextMenu.Add(new ContexMenuItem()
        {
            MenuText = "View More " + client.Name + "'s Info",
            Action = "ViewMore",
            Controller = "Clients",
            HtmlValues = null,
            RouteValues = new { id = client.ID }
        });
        contextMenu.Add(new ContexMenuItem()
        {
            MenuText = "Send a message to " + client.Name ,
            Action = "SendMessage",
            Controller = "Inbox",
            HtmlValues = null,
            RouteValues = new { id = client.ID }
        });

        ViewData["_ContextMenuList_"] = contextMenu;
```

This might be tedious, since you have to do it in all the relevant actions on a given controller. if that is the case refactor that code into a private function inside the controller and call it when it applies.

Some people might argue that this data should always be on the Model class, in this case I think of this a contextual data and not necessarily part of the model at hand. It also makes coding easier by simply putting the render code inside the master class who has no knowledge of the model. It is much like the _LogOnPartial.cshtml  that is on some of the MVC templates.